# Prove that if $u(1)=0$ then $u(t)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, legendre-polynomials

Please leave a hint and your idea not the whole solutions. 
Every idea is accepted. Please let me know what you think.

> **The Problem:** 
>   Let we have the following Legendre differential equation 
>   $$(1-t^{2})\frac{d^{2}u}{dt^{2}}-2t\frac{du}{dt}+(\chi-c^{2}t^{2})u=0.$$
>   Assume that $u$ is an entire function. I can see that if $u(1)=0$ then $u'(1)=0$ and also other order of the differention will be zero, i.e. $u^{(n)}(1)=0.$
>
> **Now my problem is that how can I see that if $u(1)=0$ then $u(t)=0.$**

Comment: If $u$ is entire, it may be written as a power series in $(z-1)$. What are the coefficients of this power series?

Comment: Oh, my god. I got the idea. I should have worked more. Thank you.